# How can I view what groups a user is in?

Tags: ownership, groups

What are some different ways to view what groups a user is in?

Comment: Are you talking about file ownership, users, or what? What research have you done?

Comment: @wjandrea, I think he needs `groups <your-username>` command to see his groups

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find out which groups a specific user is a member of, you have many choices.

### First

Issue `id USERNAME` command. Groups are listed after `groups=`.

```
$ id USERNAME
uid=1000(USERNAME) gid=1000(USERNAME) groups=1000(USERNAME),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lxd),115(lpadmin),116(sambashare)
```

### Second

`groups` shows all groups a user is member of. Groups are listed after colon (`:`).

```
$ groups USERNAME
USERNAME : USERNAME adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare
```

### Third

The file `/etc/group` keeps information about groups. First column (separated with colon) is group name and the last column is users that are members of that group.

```
$ grep USERNAME /etc/group
adm:x:4:syslog,USERNAME
cdrom:x:24:USERNAME
sudo:x:27:USERNAME
dip:x:30:USERNAME
plugdev:x:46:USERNAME
lxd:x:110:USERNAME
USERNAME:x:1000:
lpadmin:x:115:USERNAME
sambashare:x:116:USERNAME
```